# Auto Increment a non-identity Column in sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We have Non-`Identity` `Column` in our Database Which have a specific value . We have a requirement as below,

Whenever a record `insert` into that column, value should be incremented by one.

how to handle this in `sql server` ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What version of sql-server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you can use [`SEQUENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ff878370.aspx) statement  introduced in SQL Server 2012 brings the method of generating IDs

To use it in insert statement, you need to first create sequence like this -

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Id_Sequence
    AS INT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 0
    NO MAXVALUE
```

Now use it in your insert statement like this -

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.Test1
        ( orderid ,
          custid ,
          empid
        )
        SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Id_Sequence,
                @custid ,
                @empid
```

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a TRIGGER

```
CREATE TRIGGER incrementValue
ON Test
FOR Insert
AS 
   Update Test  
   set columnvalue = columnvalue +1 
   where id in (select id from inserted)
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

You can load the max value of the table and add +1

```
SELECT MAX(MyColumn)+1 FROM MyTable
```

maybe add ISNULL for first run.

```
ISNULL((SELECT MAX(MyColumn)+1 FROM MyTable),0)
```

Comment: Transactions can make a mess of this very quickly, not recommended to do max + 1.