# MySQL manual id increment

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE `batch_b`
SET `batch_b`.`printid` = @count:=@count+1;
ORDER BY postal_zone, country, airmail,company;
```

PrintID is an integer with a default value of 0. This is not the primary key.
When I run the query I expect that to give one time incremental value, but it just returned NULL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Increment a non-identity Column in sql-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821807/auto-increment-a-non-identity-column-in-sql-server)

Comment: Do you need this: `SET @count := 0;` ?  Your query looks like it should work (other than this possible typo).

Comment: I believe you need to change `Set @count = 0;` to `Declare @count int = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

It worked after wrapping the incremental value with brackets. Thank you!

```
Set @counter := 0;
UPDATE `batch_b`
SET `batch_b`.`printid` = (@counter:=@counter+1)
ORDER BY postal_zone, country, airmail,company;
```